# How to get the parent div id from the anchor child

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="wizard-rules" id="wizard-rule">If <a href="#" onclick="alert(this.id)" id="dashboard-rule-2" class="highlight">ALL DASHBOARD</a> encounters an error</div>
```

Here i want to get the div id `wizard-rule` onclick on the anchor tag. how can i do that?

the anchor tag now is just getting the id of the anchor tag itself. but not the id of its parent element.

Comment: `alert(this.parentNode.id)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `parentNode` to access on your `id`

```
<div class="wizard-rules" id="wizard-rule">If <a href="#" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.id)" id="dashboard-rule-2" class="highlight">ALL DASHBOARD</a> encounters an error</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get parent ID like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var element = document.getElementById('child').parentNode;
    alert(element.id);
}
```

Or you can use JQuery to do that:

```
var id = $('child').parent().prop('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

***1st method***:
The `parent()` method traverses to the immediate parent of each of the element in the DOM tree. `Parent()` travels a single level up the DOM.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).parent().prop("id"));
});
```

and remove the `onclick` from the Anchor tag in the HTML

***2nd Method***:

The `parentNode` property returns the parent node of the specified node, as a Node object.
In your HTML add `this.parentNode.id` to `onclick` event of `anchor` element:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(this.parentNode.id)" id="dashboard-rule-2" class="highlight">ALL DASHBOARD</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this will work fine :

```
     <div class="wizard-rules" id="wizard-rule">If <a href="#" onclick="alert($(this).parent().attr('id'))" id="dashboard-rule-2" class="highlight">ALL DASHBOARD</a> encounters an error</div>
```